# Spring boot kotlin coroutines doesn't run in parallel

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm building a backend app with spring boot and kotlin. I wanna implement a parallel execution for a specific method. I tried to use coroutines but the underlaying method runs synchronously.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
fun getXsByIds(xIds: List<String>): List<X> {
        val xList = ArrayList<X>();
        runBlocking {
            val promises = xIds.map {
                async {
                    getXById(it)
                }
            };
            
            xList.addAll((promises.awaitAll()).filterNotNull())
        }
        return xList;
    }

    fun getXById(xId: String): X? {
        // This method makes request to database
    }
```

When I put logs in `getXById` method like this

```
fun getXById(xId: String): X? {
        print("start");
        // This method makes request to database
        print("end");
    }
```

I get this output

```
start
end
start
end
start
end
...
```

Why is my coroutines not working in parallel? This is in spring boot. Not reactive. Thread per request style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `async` without specifying any coroutine elements means it will inherit them all (bar the job) from its parent. This causes your "async" call to execute on `runBlocking`s blocking dispatcher.

Try using `async(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`runBlocking` creates an ad-hoc coroutine dispatcher that uses the thread that called `runBlocking` for all coroutines. That makes it a single-threaded dispatcher, which does *not* imply it's incapable of concurrency. It will happily run any number of concurrent coroutines.

However, a single-threaded dispatcher is effective only when you use suspending, non-blocking IO, which does not seem to be your case.

This is why you have to explicitly specify the `IO` dispatcher, which is designed to support blocking code:

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    ...
}
```

While this solves your immediate problem, you should ask yourself why you're even introducing the complexity of coroutines, if you aren't actually using suspending IO? You'll get the same results by sticking to a plain Java Executor.